# Need help with a MySQL SELECT (within-group aggregate)

Tags: mysql, join

## Background

I have a table of comments. Each comment belongs to a specific row in the 'lead' table or the 'prod' table. There can be multiple comments for each row in the 'lead' and 'prod' tables. There can also be multiple comments with the same 'kstatus' for each row.

```
comments
    INT id /* primary key */
    ENUM('lead', 'prod') type /* tells me whether the comment belongs to a row in the lead table or the prod table */
    INT fid /* foreign key, refers to the id column in either the lead or prod table */
    MEDIUMTEXT comment  /* the comment itself */
    INT timestamp /* when the comment was written, i.e. 1300530201 */
    INT kstatus /* foreign key, refers to the id column in the kstatus column */

lead
    INT id
    ...

prod
    INT id
    ...

kstatus
    INT id
    ...
```

A comment with type = 'lead' and fid = 105 refers to the row in lead with lead.id = 105.
A comment with type = 'prod' and fid = 105 refers to the row in prod with prod.id = 105.

## Question

**I want to SELECT the first comment given (if any, and based on timestamp) for each row in the 'lead' table with a certain kstatus (say 14).**

Here is my attempt, which returns way too few results. Maybe due to mixing of fid's referring to lead.id and fid's referring to prod.id?

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM comments AS C1
LEFT JOIN comments AS C2 ON (C1.timestamp > C2.timestamp AND C1.fid = C2.fid)
WHERE C2.timestamp is NULL
AND C1.type = 'lead'
AND C1.kstatus = 14
GROUP BY C1.fid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c2.*
from (
    select min(c.id) realfirstcomment
    from (
        select fid, min(timestamp) as firstcomment
        from comments
        where type='lead' and kstatus=14
        group by fid
    ) f, comments c
    where f.fid = c.fid
      and c.type='lead' and c.kstatus=14
      and f.firstcomment = c.timestamp
    group by c.fid
) f2, c2
where f2.realfirstcomment = c2.id
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this gives me the first comment for each existing kstatus. That is not what I want. I want the first comment given for each lead with a specific kstatus (i.e. 14).

Comment: @arex - answer updated while you were commenting. `group by fid` => per lead

Comment: The query has `and kstatus=14` in it, so it won't give you each lead, it will give you for the specific. Have you run the query?

Comment: @Pentium - kstatus is a "type" of status. fid is an id in the leads table

Comment: Your query returns 3057 rows. This however gives me 3034: SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE kstatus = 14 AND type = 'lead' GROUP BY fid

Why does your query return more rows than there are comments with kstatus = 14 grouped by fid?

Comment: @arex that can happen if you have multiple records of the same timestamp - can you confirm?

Comment: Now this only gives me one row. It should be 3000+. I appreciate your help very much but I have the solution now.

Comment: @arex - I fixed it with a group by. You should compare the plans/performance.

Comment: Nice job Richard. Somewhat better performing too :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not only losing results because of mixing between products and leads, but between kstatus values as well -- your left join finds all rows in `C2` with a earlier timestamp, regardless of type and kstatus, as long as the `fid` is the same.

One solution would be to add `AND C1.type = C2.type AND C1.kstatus = C2.kstatus` to the join condition.

Comment: Yes! I added your suggestion and I got 3034 results. Which is exactly the same number of rows I get from : "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE kstatus = 14 AND type = 'lead' GROUP BY fid" Makes sense, no?